# Problem to create a storage bucket on Node.js

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have created a service account in the GCP IAM services, and then, I've granted the  permissions `storage.buckets.create`, `storage.buckets.get` and `storage.buckets.list` to the service account. After that, I've managed to authorize the credentials.

But when I try to create a bucket I see the following error:

> @cloud-functions-intro.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.create access to project

The code is like this:

```
const projectId = 'cloud-functions-intro';
const bucketName = `${projectId}-packaging-data`;

const storage = new Storage({
    projectId: projectId,
    keyFilename: 'my_credentials.json'
 });

 const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
```

Comment: `my_credentials.json` are the credentials for said service account, I guess? If not, please generate the credentials for it. Also, by the name and snippet, I understand this is running on Cloud Functions, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

I did a test myself and I was able to do it following the snippet code of the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library), but pointing to the keyfile as you are doing:

```
    const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

    const projectId = 'project_id';

    const storage = new Storage({
      projectId: projectId,
      keyFilename: 'credentials.json'
    });

    const bucketName = 'bucket_name';

    storage
      .createBucket(bucketName)
      .then(() => {
        console.log(`Bucket ${bucketName} created.`);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error('ERROR:', err);
      });
```

This should work. If you keep getting the same error then my recommendation is to furnish a new key for that service account and be 100% sure the keyfile you are passing is the correct one.